# remove SPAN and BR in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have filled data enclosed in a SPAN tag and BR tag for line break, in a DIV control. From the DIV, I wanted to remove a patricular text, ie removing the whole SPAN and BR associated with the text too using jquery or javascript. I tried .remove() in jquery. It seems not working. I dont know what is the correct way.

The script I used for removing the SPAN related to the ID and BR is as follows :

```
$("#<%=divMeasures.ClientID %>").find("SPAN[id=" + draggedNodeID + "]").each(function() {
                                $(draggedNodeID).remove();

                            });
```

Comment: The example text/code will help a lot to get you in the correct way...

Comment: I had put the script for removing above

Comment: can you provide a before and after of what you want the HTML to look like?  that may also help as i'm not 100% sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to diagnose without code, but try something like this:

```
$("div span,div br").remove();
```

You can replace `div` with a selector that better describes your `div` element, like an ID:

```
$("#mydiv span, #mydiv br") // ...
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

Based on your new code, try this:

```
$("#<%=divMeasures.ClientID %> span#" + draggedNodeID).remove();
```

Comment: hey thanks. This worked out for me. But how will I remove the BR tag along with the SPAN tag removed ?

Comment: But how will I remove the BR tag along with the SPAN tag removed ?

Comment: Ok. I got it. I removed that too.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you're trying to match an element by searching for a string and then remove that element.

So let's say your div was called someDiv, and you had lorem ipsum text inside a few spans, like so:

```
<div id="someDiv">
    <span>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    <span>Vivamus in sapien ut urna aliquam gravida eu nec sapien. </span>
    <span>Phasellus quis velit sit amet neque dapibus fringilla. </span>
    <span>Donec eget lorem sed sapien porttitor tincidunt quis aliquet lacus.</span>
</div>
```

Then in jQuery, I want to find the word "lorem" and remove that text.

```
$("#someDiv span:contains('lorem')").remove();
```

You can read more about the remove method on the official jQuery website.
http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Ahh you decided to post some code after all. My answer is pointless then. Nevermind.